# How to get IDs of channels under a category?

Tags: discord.js

Channels have `parent_id` that returns the category they're in, but is there anything like a `child_id` that could give me the channels a category has in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much an ID but a collection but yes. Each `categoryChannel` has a `.children` property that returns all channels inside the category.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=children

Comment: As a not, this returns a collection of all channels. If you want an array of all the channel IDs, you can use `categoryChannel.children.keyArray()`